# The meaning of the << matrix operator

Tags: c++

I see some code using `<<` with `Mat_` for matrix operations.

Example#A:

```
cv::Mat_<double> myMat_ = ( cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 
    1.0, 2.0, 3.0,
    4.0, 5.0, 6.0,
    7.0, 8.0, 9.0);
```

Example#B:

```
cv::Mat myMat = (Mat_<float>(2,3)<<1,skew,-0.5*SZ*skew,0,1,0)
cv::Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,2) << j,i);
```

What does `<<` mean in this code? Can anyone educate me a little bit?

Comment: Read the [detailed description](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#details) in the documentation of `cv::Mat` and you shall be educated. :)

Comment: Sidenote: `<<` is sometimes referred to as the Insertion Operator. `>>` is sometimes called the Extraction Operator. Whether or not insertion or extraction is involved depends on context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a shortcut for:

```
cv::Mat_<double> myMat_(3, 3);

myMat_.at(0, 0) = 1.0;
myMat_.at(0, 1) = 2.0;
myMat_.at(0, 2) = 3.0;

myMat_.at(1, 0) = 4.0;
myMat_.at(1, 1) = 5.0;
myMat_.at(1, 2) = 6.0;

myMat_.at(2, 0) = 7.0;
myMat_.at(2, 1) = 8.0;
myMat_.at(2, 2) = 9.0;
```

The `<<` and the `,` operators are overloaded to implement that behavior.